# WPF: Real time timeline control needed

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml, timeline

I need to reflect progress of execution of numerous tasks in real time.

I wondering is it any WPF\Silverlight control which do this.

Here what I found, but this controls don't meet my needs:

1. http://blogs.msdn.com/llobo/archive/2010/04/30/sl-timeline-control-for-sharepoint.aspx
2. http://timeline.codeplex.com/
3. http://timelinecontrol.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Screen%20Shots&referringTitle=Home

Comment: When you say reflect progress of execution do you mean with a progress bar or did you have some other sort of indicator?

Comment: I'm still unsure of what you are asking.  If those controls are not what you need what do you need?  The answer about the progress bar would be what if percent done is what you want, but the controls you posted lead me to believe that there is some complex functionality that you desire.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a progress bar that updates in real time, I don't know of any 3rd party controls, but you can update a standard ProgressBar control based on work being done on a background thread using the WPF Dispatcher.  I have implemented this pattern with multiple threads reporting back to multiple progress bars in a tree view simultaneously with no problems.

Here are a few articles I found that walk through this approach:

- ["WPF Multithreading Using the Background Worker and Reporting the Progress to the UI"](http://elegantcode.com/2009/07/03/wpf-multithreading-using-the-backgroundworker-and-reporting-the-progress-to-the-ui/) (ElegantCode.com)
- ["Simple WPF Progress Window with Cancellation"](http://blog.quantumbitdesigns.com/2008/07/22/simple-wpf-progress-window-with-cancellation/) (blog.quantumbitdesigns.com)